# the same convergents among 3 irrotations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions, continued-fractions, fractional-part

Let a, b, c be irrational numbers with a < b < c. If a and c have identical convergents
$\frac{p_0}{q_0}$, $\frac{p_1}{q_1}$, . . . , up to $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$, how to  prove that b also has these same convergents up to $\frac{p_1}{q_1}$.